# org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "XML;charset=ISO-8859-1": does not contain '/'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I am creating a REST API using SpringBoot(API1). which calls another Rest API using RestTemplate(API2).
API2, which I am calling require xml input and gives xml output.

XML output which API 2 sends back has a structure like below

```
    <xml>
    <IList>
        <IDetails>
            <Id>INC123</Id>
        </IDetails>
        <IDetails>
            <Id>INC124</Id>
        </IDetails>
    </IList>
</xml>
```

The Pojo Class I have created are below ones:

```
 @Data
 @XmlRootElement(name="xml")

public class IResponse implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name="IList")
    public IList iList;
}


@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="IList")
public class IList implements Serializable{
    
    @XmlElement(name="IDetails")
    public List<IDetails> iDetails;

}

@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="IDetails")
public class IDetails implements Serializable{
    
    @XmlElement(name="Id")
    public String id;
}
```

The call I am doing :

```
ResponseEntity<IList> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlTemplate, HttpMethod.POST, request, IList.class);
```

url Template is the API2 that I am calling.

When restTemplate.exchange is executed, I get status code if 200 Ok, along with error Invalid mime type "XML;charset=ISO-8859-1": does not contain '/' . When I debugged the code .I found this is being thrown by responseExtractor.extractData(response) in package org.springframework.web.client; and doExecute method.

The headers I am sending are

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

The API is getting executed successfully, Reason being backend task that the API does is occurring when I executed my flow, but the response I get is Invalid mime type "XML;charset=ISO-8859-1": does not contain '/'.

Can Anyone help me please.

Comment: the XML output isn't well formed XML. It's missing a closing document element </xml>

Comment: I edited the question. My mistake in posting the question

Comment: does it work if you explicitly set the content-type header to the string value instead of setContentType? headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);

Comment: @codebrane: No then also it does not work

Answer (score 0):

First, mime type is always has the view `type/subtype`.

I see you use Spring's `HttpHeaders` and `MediaType`. Looks like the class `MediaType` is not from Spring's package, check this. Possibly, in you 'wrong' imported class `MimeType` the value of `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` is not `application/xml` but `XML`.

You can check it manually by setting the value `application/xml`.

2nd observation: if your headers already have ACCEPT header, it will added (will be at least 2 ACCEPT headers). If you want use one header, use `.set` instead `.add`.

Comment: MediaType is from Springs Package. I tried even  using only .set. Still not working

Comment: So, give as more information. I don't see how you set headers into request.
Is it done as required: request = new HttpEntity<>(dto_in_string_format, headers);?)

Comment: yes I set the Headers into Request like this : HttpEntity<> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestbody,getHeaders()); where getHeaders set all Request Headers like :HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add()

Comment: The issue final got resolved.  The error is being thrown by RestTemplate as it always expects "/" in response header type. I used another http client for this functionality only and it worked out